# Connecting to a mysql running on a Docker container ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, docker

I have mysql container on docker. Mysql is running correcty now(because my application is running).
 When I type  `docker-compose ps` I see mysql is up. This is related part in pom.xml :

```
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3310/fraud_dev</url>
                <defaultSchemaName>abc_dev</defaultSchemaName>
                <username>abc_dev</username>
                <password>abc_dev_123</password>
```

I am trying to connect mysql on localhost terminal. I am typing this :

`mysql -u 'abc_dev'@'localhost:3310' -p`

I am typing password. Then I am getting this error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I dont know where I am wrong. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you are inside the container when you run the command, also make sure that user `abc_dev` has permission to access from localhost.

Comment: I am very new on these things. How can I sure I am inside the container?

Comment: This command to open interactive shell inside container `docker exec -it myContainerName /bin/bash`, then execute your mysql command

Comment: I did it. After type password I am getting `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abc_dev@localhost:3310'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@563fa0cad72d:/# `  My application is running with this username and password but it is saying access denied.

Comment: Make sure you enter the password correctly, also there is no need to specify the `localhost`, just try `mysql -u abc_dev -p`

Comment: Thank you. `mysql -u 'abc_dev'@'localhost:3310' -p` is not working but `mysql -u abc_dev -p` is working with same password. I connected know but I didnt understand main problem.

Comment: You are welcome, I guess the reason according to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html) to specify host, use `--host` or `-h` parameter, `mysql -h localhost -u myname -pmypass mydb`

Comment: using this way I am going container and I am connecting to mysql. Is there any way to connect out of the container?

Comment: Yes, in that case you need to do port binding, that allow incoming connections from outside to be forwarded to your container, check [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)

Answer (score 0):

You do not use the standard mysql port `3306`. Because of this you have to specify the used port with

```
mysql -u abc_dev -p -h localhost --port 3310
```

Comment: I think its about in docker-compose.yml :                                                              `mysql-db:
         image: mysql:5.7.11
           command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1
           ports:
            - "3310:3306"
        env_file:
            - ./env-variables/commons.env`

Comment: Thats right. But the mysql cli-client does not know anything about docker. You have to tell the mysq Client where to look for the mysql server. If not the client assumes you want to connect to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. I edited my post with better code

Comment: I tried as you write : `mysql -u abc_dev -p -h localhost --port 3310` but `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` did not changed.

Comment: try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost